# dcast fun.aggregate parameters

Tags: r, reshape2

In the R package `reshape2`, does the `dcast()` function parameter fun.aggregate= have the ability to accept parameters itself?

For instance:

```
dcast(dataFrame, x ~ y, value.var = 'z', fun.aggregate = mean(na.rm = TRUE))
```

I'm asking because I use my own function for the fun.aggregate parameter, and I'd rather not hard code the parameters into a growing list of functions.

This website is great; thanks everyone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like many functions in R, `dcast` has a `...` argument that is typically used to pass additional arguments on to a function. In fact, at `?dcast`, you'll find this line in the "arguments section":

> `...` *further arguments are passed to aggregating function*

Thus, the correct way of writing your example would be:

```
dcast(dataFrame, x ~ y, value.var = 'z', fun.aggregate = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```